# Casting LineString to Polygon results in ClassCastException when y coordinates are the same

Tags: polygon, java, linestring, jts-topology-suite

```
final WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
String geomString = "MULTILINESTRING ((-98.753985 34.63093, -98.7555568 34.63093))";
MultiLineString geom = (MultiLineString)wktReader.read(geomString);
LineString newGeom = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(geom.getCoordinates());
Polygon envelope = (Polygon) newGeom.getEnvelope();
```

Such code results with ClassCastException(). However, when I'm changing y value of any of coordinates, e.g. first one to 34.6309**4**, I don't get any error.
I am using `org.locationtech.jts-1.17`.

What would I like to achieve is to cast it to Polygon without this Exception.
Or, the exception is actually valid and I shouldn't be able to cast any two-coordinate LineString to Polygon?

Comment: Three distinct vertex locations are required to construct a Polygon (which will have four vertices). WKT for a POLYGON requires all four vertices (first and last the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your MultiLineString is a vertical line JTS gives you back a line when you ask for the envelope (it thinks this is helpful). So you need to ask for the `internalEnvelope` which will give you an `Envelope` (an xmin/xmax, ymin/ymax). You can then convert this into a `Polygon` using the `org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS` [Utility class](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/main/jts.html).

```
final WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader();
String geomString = "MULTILINESTRING ((-98.753985 34.63093, -98.7555568 34.63093))";
MultiLineString geom = (MultiLineString) wktReader.read(geomString);
LineString newGeom = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(geom.getCoordinates());
Geometry envelope = newGeom.getEnvelope();
System.out.println(envelope);
Envelope env = newGeom.getEnvelopeInternal();
System.out.println(env);
Polygon polygon = JTS.toGeometry(env);
System.out.println(polygon);
```

Which produces:

```
LINESTRING (-98.7555568 34.63093, -98.753985 34.63093)
Env[-98.7555568 : -98.753985, 34.63093 : 34.63093]
POLYGON ((-98.7555568 34.63093, -98.753985 34.63093, -98.753985 34.63093, -98.7555568 34.63093, -98.7555568 34.63093))
```

Note: the polygon will still look like a line as it has no width, but I guess that is what you want.

Comment: I've justed looked up this `getEnvelope` function and now I understand why last expression works for a line which is not vertical. It outputs envelope, that has four coordinates, while for vertical line it outputs Linestring with two points. I think that was missing in my thought process. And yes, this is what I want, cause I use Polygon type in further code. Thank you.